# How do I verify a Google idToken in .net core

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-authentication

I have a .Net Core application.

I need to verify a google idToken.

One way is to call tokeninfo endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123

Do you know another way? Which .Net library do you prefer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate Google Id Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061310/validate-google-id-token)